# REST API Design for special actions on resources

Tags: rest, architecture, action

I need to design an operation “duplicate” for "articles".

My thought was: a `POST` on `apibaseurl/articles/{id}/duplicates` and returning a `200 OK` with the URI of the created duplicate, which's URI however will conform to the template `apibaseurl/articles/{id}`.

When issuing a `GET` to `apibaseurl/articles/{id}/duplicates` however, there will not necessarily be a list of duplicates (meaning: the server will not keep track of all duplicates created for an article - the "duplicate" relationship is ignored by the server outside the scope of the request)

Questions:

1. is my suggested solution OK?
2. does it not violate any RESTful principle by having the URI of the created object point to a location not under the resource under which it was posted?
3. would I have to provide a client with the possibility to list all duplicates for an article?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you create an article but not with a `POST apibaseurl/articles/` but with a `POST apibaseurl/articles/{id}/duplicates`? What do you mean by 'there will not necessarily be a list of duplicates'? Will this ever or never return a collection? In which cases? Will an article created as a duplicate be different from the same article created using the 'normal' way?

Comment: Concerning your first question: yes. By this, it is meant to underline the intent to create a duplicate (i.e. everything except the generated identifier is copied from the "source" article to a new one).

Comment: Concerning your other questions: it is not yet sure whether there will be a list of duplicates in the future, for now there is no requirement to have one. The duplicates will only be different from the originals by their automatically generated id. They however will most likely be updated soon after and evolve into something similar, but different in more than one attribute from the original.

Answer (score 0):

> is my suggested solution OK?

It looks fine to me.

> does it not violate any RESTful principle by having the URI of the created object point to a location not under the resource under which it was posted?

No, that is not necessary. You `POST` to a collection resource but this does not force you to return a `Location` header pointing inside this collection.

> would I have to provide a client with the possibility to list all duplicates for an article?

If you have a use case for this, you could provide it. But if there is no business interest in listing the articles created as duplicates of an existing article, you don't have to.

Go ahead :)